# Is there a way to get all registered protocol handlers in JS?

Tags: javascript, browser, protocols, custom-protocol, protocol-handler

So I'm trying to make a web app that basically serves as a URL shortener, where I can use a custom protocol with `navigator.registerProtocolHandler` (I know that this isn't a very good idea for various reasons, but I just want to try messing around with it). For example, `web+yt:` redirects me to YouTube, and `web+yt:htb` redirects me to HowToBasic's channel. This works so far, but the question is if there's a way to query which protocol handlers have been registered? There's also the `navigator.unregisterProtocolHandler` function to unregister them, but I cannot find anything about a listing function. I could store it into a cookie or `localStorage`, but if I clear the website data I'd have to guess which ones are registered, which isn't a really good solution. Do you guys know any solutions? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need this list? What are you going to "store into a cookie or localStorage"?

Comment: Because i want to unregister them later, and thereby uninstalling the shortener. I was thinking about putting the already registered handlers into a cookie/localstorage in order to unregister them later, but as I said, if they get cleared, I'd have to guess again.

Comment: Just unregister them unconditionally. If they're not registered, nothing bad happens.

Comment: amusingly, safety could be a use for this list. Say, we want show a mailto button only if the handler is verysecuremailhosting.org; or we do not want to show a button for the handler if the list of registered hosts includes some known phishing site

Comment: @arivero Security would rather dictate *not* to expose this list, since it'll be abused for [browser fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint). And while exposing the list of registered protocols might be useful, exposing the handlers would definitely be a privacy issue.